# How do I fill these `NaN` values properly?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here's my original dataframe with `NaN` values which I'm trying to fill;

https://prnt.sc/i40j33

If I use `df.interpolate(axis=1)` to fill up the `NaN` values, only some of the rows fill up properly with a number.
For e.g

https://prnt.sc/i40mgq

As you can see in the screenshot column:1981 and row:3 which had a `NaN` value has filled up properly with a value other than `NaN`. I want to fill the rest of `NaN` as well like that? Any idea how do I do that?

Comment: Screenshots don't work here. Post raw data please.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using `DataFrame.interpolate()`**

In your case it is failing because there are no columns to the left, and therefore the interpolate method doesn't know what to interpolate it to: `missing_value = (left_value + right_value)/2`

So you could, for example, insert a column to the left with all 0's (if you would like to impute your missing values on the first column with half of the next value), as such:

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='allZeroes', value=0)
```

After this, you could interpolate as you are doing and remove the column

**General missing value imputation**
Either use `df.fillna('DEFAULT-VALUE')` as Alex mentioned in the comments to the question. [Docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

or do something like:

`df.my_col[df.my_col.isnull()] = 'DEFAULT-VALUE'`

I'd recommend using the `fillna` as you can use methods such as forward fill (`ffill`) -- impute the missings with the previous value -- and other similar methods.

Comment: Thanks man! That helped a lot! I've been trying out a lot of stuffs on this dataframe for the past one or two weeks and couldn't figure out shit!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might want to interpolate on `axis=0`, column-wise:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(35, dtype=float).reshape(5,7),
                      columns=[1951, 1961, 1971, 1981, 1991, 2001, 2001],
                      index=range(0, 5))
>>> df.iloc[1:3, 0] = np.nan
>>> df.iloc[3, 3] = np.nan

>>> df.interpolate(axis=0)
   1951  1961  1971  1981  1991  2001  2001
0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
1   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0
2  14.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0
3  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0
4  28.0  29.0  30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0
```

Currently you're interpolating row-wise.  `NaN`s that "begin" a Series aren't padded by a value on either side, making interpolation impossible for them.

**Update**: pandas is [adding some more optionality for this in v 0.23.0](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#dataframe-interpolate-has-gained-the-limit-area-kwarg).